# How to select a single child class based on its parent class on CSS and jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, class, media-queries, parent

Hello im making a site where users can post something.
I would like to use media queries so it can be used on mobile phones unfortunately i have to switch some div tags to change the layout.

because media query css cant change the div layout im using the jquery function insertBefore

i want to move div three before div one

this was my attempt http://jsfiddle.net/PnUTX/

```
$(function() {
    $(".three").insertBefore(".one");
});
```

too bad thats not what i want and i would like this result http://jsfiddle.net/Bvdby/

i tried looking for solutions but i only found where you toggle show/hide using $(this) but im not selecting a specific div class but every class

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $(".three").each(function() {
        $(this).insertBefore($(this).siblings(".one"));
    });
});
```

As three elements matches `.one` and `.three` selector. All three `.three` elements inserted before all three `.one` element. (Tongue Twister ;-))

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/PnUTX/4/

```
$(function() {
    $(".box").each(function(){
        var this_box=$(this);
        this_box.find('.one').before( this_box.find('.three'));
    });
});
```